# pm2 cron running automatically on start

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, pm2

I am trying to use pm2 to run a cron at midnight.

With this setup I am facing an unexpected scenario where the cron is triggered once as soon as I start the process.

**Is there a way this can be configured without having to validate running time in cron process ?**

ecosystem.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "server",
      script: "server.js",
      watch: false,
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: "production"
      }
    },
    {
      name: "test-cron",
      script: "test-cron.js",
      instances: 1,
      exec_mode: "fork",
      cron_restart: "0 0 * * *",
      watch: false,
      autorestart: false,
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: "production"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Command

```
pm2-runtime ecosystem.config.js
```

test-cron.js

```
console.log("CRON EXECUTED");
```

Console output:

```
> pm2-test@1.0.0 start /Users/sudhirshrestha/workspace/pm2-test
> pm2-runtime ecosystem.config.js

2019-08-28T22:54:44: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
2019-08-28T22:54:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-28T22:54:44: PM2 log: App [test-cron:1] starting in -fork mode-
2019-08-28T22:54:44: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
2019-08-28T22:54:44: PM2 log: App [test-cron:1] online
CRON EXECUTED
2019-08-28T22:54:49: PM2 log: App [test-cron:1] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
```

Issue: Cron autoruns once immediately on start

Answer (score 2):

As the pm2 docs say, "Application must be running for cron feature to work", so of course, your thing will run once when you start it.
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#control-flow

The feature is designed to restart a program that is already running, not periodically run something that isn't running now. PM2 is about managing long-running processes. It's not about firing off a little short-running program periodically.  For what you want, why not just use a regular cron job?

Answer (score 0):

It is not documented, but based on the ENV variables there is way to know if the script is started or restarted.

- it does not have `prev_restart_delay`
- it has `restart_time: '0'` (though unfortunately if you stop the script it will start with '0' again)

So inside your `test-cron.js` you can add the following:

```
if (!process.env.prev_restart_delay) {
    process.exit(0);
  }
```

this will stop your script but it still will be restarted on cron defined, and this condition will be skipped then.

Also I noticed that pm2 adds ENV variable `'exit_code': '0'` after restarting, so you may also use this alternative condition:

```
if (!process.env.exit_code) {
  process.exit(0);
}
```